# specifying order of items in android

Tags: android, input

I have a list of items lets say for example "a", "b", "c". As an input from the user, i would like to have an order specified for these items, for example {a, c, b} or {b, c, a} etc. Is there a standard way in android to take these kinds of inputs or it would be great if anyone could suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: Please go into more detail. Ie: paste code

Comment: Please, more details / explanations of what you are trying to do... !!

Comment: I do not have any existing code. This is a task that i would like to achieve i.e receiving an order as an input from the user.

Comment: If i provide the user with strings "a", "b", "c" then user provide an order of these strings such as {a, b, c} or {b, c, a} etc as input. Is there a nice way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an overly broad question. Questions like how long the list is could be may be important, but:

I'd recommend a drag and drop function for the user [reordering of listview items by drag and drop using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141144/reordering-of-listview-items-by-drag-and-drop-using-android) as that would be pretty natural and fluid for the user to use for reordering.

Then you can save your listview state: [Saving advanced state of an Android Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566206/saving-advanced-state-of-an-android-listview) If you wanted to save it to a DB or something I don't know because of the overly broad question, but you could do anything like that too.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.Reordering items in list view definitely sounds like a good solution to my problem. There are 4 items in the list.

Comment: That should be perfect then, I think Pandora uses something similar, and they have up to 100 possible stations in their list, so 4 would be no problem/hassle for the user. Have fun, Thanks.